# How to log REST API request and response metrics in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, logging

I want to capture and log the details of every API request and response including the error/exceptions in my Spring Boot application in a JSON format. Details such as Status Code, Exception, Timestamp of the request, execution in seconds are to be logged.

The log should be captured in the following format for every API request. Kindly advise on any Spring Boot library that can be used to achieve this.

```json
{
  "timestamp_log": " 2019-01-29 09:34:00.895",
  " request_type": "POST",
  " statusCode": "200",
  "error classification": “Technical / Functional ",
  " error_type": "NOT SPECIFIED",
  " execution_time_milliseconds ": 243
}
```

Comment: Zalando's logbook can definitely do the job. I wrote an article recently on how we did it. Have a look https://medium.com/@pramodyahk/configure-request-response-logging-for-spring-boot-quickly-using-logbook-183503c4676c

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly prefer to delegate this task to a dedicated library like **Logbook** : https://github.com/zalando/logbook

It's easy to implement, and highly customisable if you need more from it (you can easily add a *correlation id* for example).

You will need the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${logbook.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a very simple configuration used to inject the required bean to log the requests/responses:

```java
@Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Logbook logbook() {
        final var defaultHttpLogFormatter = new DefaultHttpLogFormatter();
        final var defaultHttpLogWriter = new DefaultHttpLogWriter();
        final var sink = new DefaultSink(defaultHttpLogFormatter, defaultHttpLogWriter);
        return Logbook.builder().sink(sink).build();
    }
}
```

While it's very handy I don't think you will be able to personalize the properties name, but you will be able to filter what you don't need.
With the default implementation you can print the duration (see: https://github.com/zalando/logbook?tab=readme-ov-file#response).
You will need an extra library if the JSON log format is a requirement for you (see: https://github.com/zalando/logbook?tab=readme-ov-file#json):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
  <artifactId>logbook-json</artifactId>
</dependency>
```